# "Visualization" of dangling pointer

Tags: c, pointers, visualization

While learning pointers I tried pointer declarations/dereferenciations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int *call() {

int a = 3;

 return &a;
}

int main() {
   printf("call* is: %d\n", *call());
   printf("call is: %p\n", call());
   Sleep(2000);

   printf("call* is: %d\n", *call());
   printf("call is: %p\n", call());
   Sleep(2000);

   printf("call* is: %d\n", *call());
   printf("call is: %p\n", call());
   return 0;
}
```

So "obviously" the "a" is a local variable.
But my problem is,
when I'm reading out the address of "a", it's always the same address.
Why is that like this?

PS: I'm running a prime-number-calculator in the background to fill up as much memory as possible and I put in the "Sleep" to make the program wait, but still the address of "a" is always the same.

Comment: There are no other threads in your program; how can you be running anything in the background? Is your refridgerator running in the background, too?

Comment: Ok :)  I hope you have your fun.
But can you tell me how i can "see"/"visualize" that the address of "a" is not constant?

Comment: Almost all of your assumptions are wrong and make no sense. Please look up "undefined behaviour" first of all. Then, if you're still decided on this career, go and look at the generated machine code to see what's going on.

Comment: Processes have their own virtual address space. It doesn't matter that you are running other processes such as a prime number calculator in the background. That will not affect the address space of your test program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is located on the stack of the current thread : every time the function `call()` is run, it "allocates" 4 bytes on the stack to stock `a`, return the address and then "frees" the space it uses on stack (it is not actually allocating/freeing anything, just offsetting the stack pointer).

So if you call it several times in a row, the state of the stack on input of the function will be exactly the same, so the actual address of `a` on the stack the same every time (please note that this address is invalid as soon as you exit the function).

You should do something like

```
int * call2(){
    int a = 0;
    int *b = call();
    printf("%d",a); 
    return b;
}
```

and then

```
int *a = call();
int *b = call2();
```

You will see `a` and `b` will be different (the `printf` is there to make sure the compiler does not optimise anything away)

Since the stack is local to the current thread (not influenced by other processes/threads), your prime number calculator and `Sleep` are to no use at all.

Comment: Many thanks for the effort!
I'm slowly getting the clue of the mechanics.

Comment: Your welcome. Be sure to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack for a detailed look. This **will** help you getting a better understanding of what's going on. Once you are satisfied with any answer, be sure to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: I have to thank you again, because in another example I could check, that the given solution must be wrong, when I use your code to check the addresses.

Answer (score 1):

"call" is to return a pointer to a variable? The problem here is that "a" is not statically allocated, but is on the *stack*. You can return its address at the moment (which may or may not be the same address, depending on whether "call" is invoked at the same depth each time), but there's no guarantee of what that address is pointing to once you return from "call". You put a 3 in it during the call, and that may be overwritten by something else by the time you get around to looking at the contents of that address.

Comment: Thank you, I had some suggestions in my mind leading to this.